# What do Mexicans always mutter to me after I say, "Feliz año"?

Tags: saludos, méxico

When I say, "Feliz año" to Mexicans, they usually mutter something and trail off. Is this a standard response to my holiday valediction, am I being dissed, or am I being neurotic?

Comment: Can you tell us maybe what it _sounds_ like they're saying? This might help clue us in...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm mexican and when someone says to you "Feliz año" you usually respond:

> Gracias, igualmente.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like the right amount of syllables in the response.

Comment: Of course, if you like being neurotic, I can point out that there are a lot of other messages with that same amount of syllabes :-p